# Angular 6 - Click event binding not working for checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using reactive form to present a list of heroes to user and want to trigger a console log when user selects a hero by clicking on checkbox.

So, the problem is when i print this.form in console I get the correct value, but when i print this.form.value, I get the value of previous state.

Screenshot of when 1 Hero is selected

[image: 1 Hero Selected]

As you can see, when 1 hero is selected, this.form is printing the correct values but this.form.value is printing the previous state, i.e when no values were selected.

Screenshot of when 2 Hero is selected

[image: 2 hero selected]

Similarly for 2 heroes. Showing result of previous state, i.e when 1 hero is selected.

The code for the same is below.

```
 <div class="lists">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="select()">
      <ul formArrayName="assets" class="heroes p-2">
      <li class="p-2" *ngFor="let asset of form.controls.assets.controls; let i = index"
          [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
          (click)="select()">
          <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
          {{heroes[i].name}}
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button>submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-commands',
  templateUrl: './commands.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commands.component.scss']
})
export class CommandsComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  selectedHero;
  heroes = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice', isChecked: false },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco', isChecked: false },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto', isChecked: false },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas', isChecked: false },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta', isChecked: false },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan', isChecked: false },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama', isChecked: false },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ', isChecked: false },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma', isChecked: false },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado', isChecked: false },
  ];

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {
                this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                  assets: new FormArray([])
                });
                this.addCheckboxes();
              }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private addCheckboxes() {
    this.heroes.forEach((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl();
      (this.form.controls.assets as FormArray).push(control);
    });
  }

  select() {
    console.log(this.form);
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

  onSelect(hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: Try using the change event instead of click event and use it on the input element instead of on the li element.

Comment: The method  select() is pit in onSubmit in form and on click in li , so the method onSubmit is getting the latest value.the second thing is if you put a settimeout for form.value will it get the latest result or keeps the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the "click" event handler is executed before the form object is updated. As shown in the other answer, a "change" event handler will update the form as expected.

Confusion is caused by the visualisation of the form object in the browser console. When you log this.form, you see its properties with their latest values. When you log this.form.value, you get the current value of that property and this is its actual value in the moment of logging.

Comment: I am able to meet my goals with change event handler. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="lists">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="select()">
      <ul formArrayName="assets" class="heroes p-2">
      <li class="p-2" *ngFor="let asset of form.controls.assets.controls; let i = index"
          [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
          >
          <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (change)="select()">
          {{heroes[i].name}}
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button>submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.